# fix my initialData in react-query why doesn't work

Tags: javascript, next.js, react-query

I tried to make code using initialData, but none of the output comes out even the key doesn't appear in react-query-dev-tool
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCtHL.png)

```
import { useQuery, useQueryClient } from 'react-query';
import axios from 'axios';

interface CustomError {
  message: string;
}

interface User {
  id: number;
  first_name: string;
  last_name: string;
  email: string;
  gender: string;
  ip_address: string;
  description: string;
  location: string;
  password: string;
  mac_address: string;
  url: string;
}

export async function fetchUserDataById({ queryKey }: any): Promise<User> {
  const dataId = queryKey[1]
  const response = await axios.get<User>(`http://localhost:5000/users/${dataId}`);
  return response.data;
}

export const useDataUserById = (id: number) => {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();

  return useQuery<User, CustomError>(['user-data', id], fetchUserDataById, {
    initialData: () => {
      const users = queryClient.getQueryData<User[]>('one-data');
      if (users) {
        const dataUser = users?.find((userData) => userData.id === id);
        if(dataUser){
            console.log(dataUser)
            return dataUser
        }
      }
      return undefined;
    },
  });
};
```

solve the problem why my initialData on react-query does'nt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to check the query key or data structure, there's might be a mismatch and make sure to check if the initial data you're trying to retrieve using `queryClient.getQueryData` has been successfully cached in the `queryClient`.

you can add logs to debug each process.

```
export const useDataUserById = (id: number) => {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();

  return useQuery<User, CustomError>(['user-data', id], fetchUserDataById, {
    initialData: () => {
      // Debugging: Check the key you're using for initial data retrieval
      console.log("Initial data query key:", 'one-data');
      
      const users = queryClient.getQueryData<User[]>('one-data');
      
      // Debugging: Log the retrieved users data
      console.log("Retrieved users data:", users);
      
      if (users) {
        const dataUser = users.find((userData) => userData.id === id);
        if (dataUser) {
          // Debugging: Log the found dataUser
          console.log("Found dataUser:", dataUser);
          return dataUser;
        }
      }
      return undefined;
    },
  });
};
```